# How to use 'Event Manager Shortcodes' plugin via the php code?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I am using [Event Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager/) plugin. I want to use many of the shortcodes via php code. e.g [events_calendar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can do any shortcode with `do_shortcode()` (see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)). But if they have a template function available, its probably best to use that.

```
 echo do_shortcode('[events_calendar]');
```

Comment: thanks dude its working and now I can use any shortcode.

Comment: now one more problem is there.  do_shortcode('[events_calendar]'); this is working fine but I want to use <?php echo do_shortcode('[events_calendar  long_events=1]') . it's not working

Comment: @Bhuvnesh It *should* work. You can pass attributes like that with `do_shortcode`. A bug with the plug-in perhaps? Probably best to ask them on the plug-in forums as there's not much else to add here :).

Comment: Perhaps set the value in double quotes, like '[events_calender long_events="1"]'

Comment: @bueltge I don't *think* that matters. At least I know `[shortcode attribute=true]` passes the value of attribute as a string rather than boolean.

Comment: @StephenHarris yes, you are right on default. But I had seen not seldom, that plugin developers filter the data a little bid wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think `em-template-tags.php` may have what you're looking for

EDIT

Per [Events Manager's documentation](http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/template-tags/), template tags can be found within the file `em-template-tags.php`, which is in the root of the plugin directory.

For example, `[locations_list $atts]` would have the corresponding template tag `em_locations()`. I just tried this example on a clean WP 3.5 install and the results are the same.

2ND EDIT

Alternatively, you can just call the function to which the shortcode is hooked. `em-shortcode.php`, also in the plugin root, has all of the shortcodes and corresponding functions in it.

For your example of `[events_calendar]`, `<?php echo em_get_calendar_shortcode(); ?>` displays the calendar just as the shortcode would.

Answer (score 0):

Specific Events Manager template tags are another way to achieve this, for example:

```
<?php 
echo EM_Events::output(array('scope'=>'tomorrow', 'limit'=>10, ));
?>
```

You can use any of the attributes. (http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/event-search-attributes/)

One of the attributes is, 'format', which formats the output and lets you use html and all the placeholders (http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/placeholders/) and conditional tags.

So you can do this:

```
<?php 
echo EM_Events::output(array('scope'=>'tomorrow', 'limit'=>10, 'format'=>' 

    <div>#_EVENTNAME</div> 
    <div>#_EVENTDATES</div>
{has_location}
    <div>#_LOCATIONNAME</div>
{/has_location}

'));
?>
```